# how to fetch all registered users from XMPP library ios? I have tried this but getting error code 404, item is not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>" error:&error];

XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"DOMAIN"]

[appDel_friends.xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

I got an Error error code 404 item not found.

Request:

```
SEND: <iq type="get" to="ios.ioschat.com" id="44BF120A-83F5-4AB8-85AD-006D752B716E"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" node="all users"/></iq>
```

Response:

```
RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="44BF120A-83F5-4AB8-85AD-006D752B716E" from="ios.ioschat.com" to="user928@ios.ioschat.com/1661f8e6"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" node="all users"/><error code="404" type="cancel"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not attaching the query. Do something like:

```
 NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>"
                                                            error:&error];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get"
                                 to:yourJID
                          elementID:[appDel_friends.xmppStream generateUUID] child:query];
    [appDel_friends.xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all registered users from XMPP library :

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>"
                                                        error:&error];
XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get"
                             to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"DOMAIN"]
                      elementID:[_xmppStream generateUUID] child:query];
[_xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```